# Removing spaces after all commas

Tags: regex, sed

I have a a CSV file which has a space after every comma.  I wish to remove the space after every comma and I try something like:

```
sed -e 's/ ,/,/g' local.csv > localNoSpaces.csv
```

But this only removes the space after the first comma on each line. How do I remove the space after all commas?

Thanks.

Comment: After, I have Uudated question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just in case that the spaces are not spaces but tabs and spaces you could use

```
 sed -e 's/\s\+,/,/g' local.csv > localNoSpaces.csv
```

or if they are after each comma use

```
 sed -e 's/,\s\+/,/g' local.csv > localNoSpaces.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regex removes the space before the comma, not after it:

```
sed -e 's/, /,/g' local.csv > localNoSpaces.csv
```

If there can be more than one space, use the `+` quantifier:

```
sed -e 's/, \+/,/g' local.csv > localNoSpaces.csv
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if I have a comma followed by more than one space?

Comment: @dublintech: if there are more whitespaces just use `s/,[ ]\+/,/g`