# Unix Sed to remove leading and trailing spaces in the CSV formatted file without considering String value which has comma

Tags: sed

Referred the solution given in the link [Smarter Removing Unnecessary WhiteSpace CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206556/smarter-removing-unnecessary-whitespace-csv/18667342#18667342)

Need to have this implemented using unix sed.

Source CSV file has the data like this :

```
"112", 21,,"4563446" , "VASQUE, HILARI", 365, "LOPEZ, ESTHER O" ,"16:06","00:00",, , 267.95, 463.48,"Test"
```

Expected OutPut CSV file:

```
"112",21,,"4563446","VASQUE, HILARI",365,"LOPEZ, ESTHER O","16:06","00:00",,,267.95,463.48,"Test"
```

Comment: I formatted the question. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for future reference.

Comment: Can a string contain an escaped quote?

Answer (score 3):

Use the proper tool to parse the CSV. For example, [Text::CSV_XS](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aCSV_XS) in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Text::CSV_XS;
my $csv = 'Text::CSV_XS'->new({ binary => 1,
                                allow_whitespace => 1,
                                eol => $/,
                              })
        or die 'Text::CSV_XS'->error_diag;

my @rows;
while (my $row = $csv->getline(*DATA)) {
    push @rows, $row;
}
$csv->eof or $csv->error_diag;

$csv->print(*STDOUT, $_) for @rows;

__DATA__
"112", 21,,"4563446" , "VASQUE, HILARI", 365, "LOPEZ, ESTHER O" ,"16:06","00:00",, , 267.95, 463.48,"Test"
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^/\n/;ta;:a;s/\n$//;t;s/\n("[^"]*")/\1\n/;ta;s/\n(\S+)/\1\n/;ta;s/\n\s+/\n/;ta' file
```

This inserts a marker at the front of the line and uses it to anchor a regex to remove leading spaces. The marker moves through the line until it reaches the end and is then removed.

On reflection an alternative solution using sed is:

```
sed -r 's/("[^"]*"|[^,]+|,)\s*,\s*/\1,/g' file
```

Comment: +1. Phenomenal, but as with many sed solutions, essentially unmaintainable

Comment: @Potong, 
<br/> I tried with the given solution: <br/>
** sed 's/("[^"]*"|[^,]+|,)\s*,\s*/\1,/g' SourceFile > FinalOutputFile **  <br/> 
           
** sed: 0602-404 Function s/("[^"]*"|[^,]+|,)\s*,\s*/\1,/g cannot be parsed.  **   
<br/> <br/>
Added backslash in front of replace string \1, and executed the Sed : 
<br/> <br/>
** sed 's/("[^"]*"|[^,]+|,)\s*,\s*/\\1,/g' SourceFile > FinalOutputFile. **
<br/>
It doesn’t seem to remove the leading spaces from string and decimal value.                                                             
<br/>
Am I doing any wrong here?

Comment: @user2755789 I think you may have missed the important `-r` switch at the start of the command.

Comment: Thanks @Potong for the reply. When I tried with -r option, i got the following error :                                                                                                                                            $ sed -r 's/("[^"]*"|[^,]+|,)\s*,\s*/\1,/g' SourceFile > FinalOutputFile
sed: Not a recognized flag: r
Usage: sed [-n] [-u] Script [File ...]
 sed [-n] [-u] [-e Script] ... [-f Script_file] ... [File ...]