# CSV with additional whitespace

Tags: python, pandas, csv

How can I read the file with `11` and `12`, and `23` and `24` at the correct place?

For example, the numbers `11` and `12` should be in `x3` and `x4` variables, respectively.

The MWE can be seen below (obs.: `csv` format).

```
x1;x2;x3;x4;
1;2;3;4;
5;6;7;8;
9;10;;11;12
13;14;15;16;
17;18;19;20;
21;22;;23;24
```

## Edit - Illustration of real example

[Dataset snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Flhl.png)

Comment: I think you need to define what you believe is the *"Correct place"*. 
Also, you appear to have missed your code out of the MWE

Comment: For example, the numbers `11` and `12` should be in `x3` and `x4` variables, respectively.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Smarter Removing Unnecessary WhiteSpace CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206556/smarter-removing-unnecessary-whitespace-csv)

Comment: @man0s this solution is used for whitespace in string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption is that ur 'correct' place is column x4. You can pass in a regular expression for sep, which will split the data on one or more occurences of ';':

```
data = '''x1;x2;x3;x4;
          1;2;3;4;
          5;6;7;8;
          9;10;;11;12
          13;14;15;16;
          17;18;19;20;
          21;22;;23;24'''

pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),sep='[;]+',engine='python').iloc[:,:-1]

    x1  x2  x3  x4
0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8
2   9   10  11  12
3   13  14  15  16
4   17  18  19  20
5   21  22  23  24
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. My data are `csv` files, in this case, isn't working. I need to read from `csv` file directly.

Comment: did u include StringIO when u were actually reading the data? just remove the StringIO when reading ur own data.

Comment: I put a snapshot of the dataset.

Comment: @WagnerSilva We'll need to have a look at the raw data to see what the problem is (the problem seems to be in column 'AX' in this case).

Answer (score 1):

This csv file has 5 columns: x1,x2,x3,x4 and a column without a name (after the last semicolon).

The only correct place for 11 and 12 (and 23 and 24) is in the x4 and the fifth column.

If you want those in x3 and x4 instead, you'll have to remove the extra `;` before 11 and 23.

---

You may want to check your original files to see if there are separators inside the fields.

Comment: This is a minimum worked example (MWE), in my problem there are large number of rows and many csv.

Comment: Do they have the same problem, or do you have some separators inside the fields maybe? If they are like your example, the (creation of the) csv files should be fixed, not the parsing.

Comment: @WagnerSilva Are you able to provide some real data (or some of the problem rows from those files) to have a look at?